# Dynamic expression variables for validation messages in Spring MessageSource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I am using **Hibernate Validator** and a `MessageSource` to localize violation messages.

```
class FooValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidFoo, Foo>

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidTransitions constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Foo foo, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        //some calculations

        String result = calculations.toString();

        HibernateConstraintValidatorContext hibernateContext = context.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class);
        hibernateContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        hibernateContext.addExpressionVariable("invalidResult", result)
                .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Invalid field: ${invalidResult}")
                .addConstraintViolation();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to have something like this in `messages.properties`:

```
ValidFoo.foo=Localized invalid field message, field: ${invalidResult}
```

But I can't find a way to inject dynamic parameters from my `FooValidator` to message property.

Comment: Did ou try Autowiring MessageSource class and do Message.getMessage().

Comment: @pvpkiran of course. My localization works in general, but I am a bit confused about this case with expression variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named parameters and expression variables can be resolved only by Hibernate.

Spring uses MessageFormat.

See AbstractMessageSource.getMessageInternal for details.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be a comment. Once you get enough reputation, you'll be able to leave comments on the site.

Comment: @rosário-pereira-fernandes For the blind, answer in the first two lines